# Why is PHP inserting backticks into my table?

Tags: php, ajax, html-table

I am confounded by this behavior. Here is the output:

[image]

PHP table creation:

```
$table = '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Work Type</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>PDF</th>
            <th class="fa fa-envelope-o" style="font-size: larger; color: blue;" title="Send Writer Email"></th>
            <th class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size: larger; color: green;"  title="Request Manuscript"></th>
            <th>Rating</th>
        </tr></thead><tbody>';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $table .= "<tr class='trow'>
        <td class='fullname'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
        <td class='title'>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>
        <td class='form-type'>" . $row['FormType'] . "</td>
        <td class='genre'>" . $row['Genre'] . "</td>
        <td><a class='synopsis' href='uploads/" . $row['Filename'] . "' target='_blank'>synposis</a></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' class='sendemail' /></td>`
        <td><input type='checkbox' class='email-request-manuscript' /></td>
        <td><div class='rating'></div></td>
        <td class='hidden email'>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>
        <td class='hidden id'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>
        <td><input class='hidden writer-rating' value='" . $row['Rating'] . "'/></td>
        </tr>";
};
$table .= "</tbody></table></div>";
echo $table;
```

JS (retrieves table from PHP)

```
$('#table-list').empty().append(table);
console.log($('#table-list').html());
```

console.log (one table row)

```
<div class="table-responsive">`
                `
                `
                `
                `
                `
                `
                `
                <table class="table table-stripped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Work Type</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>PDF</th>
                    <th class="fa fa-envelope-o" style="font-size: larger; color: blue;" title="Send Writer Email"></th>
                    <th class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size: larger; color: green;" title="Request Manuscript"></th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                </tr></thead><tbody><tr class="trow">
                <td class="fullname">Ron Tornambe</td>
                <td class="title">The Hunting of the Snark</td>
                <td class="form-type">Short Story</td>
                <td class="genre">Absurdist/surreal/whimsical</td>
                <td><a class="synopsis" href="uploads/3752805599.pdf" target="_blank">synposis</a></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="sendemail"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="email-request-manuscript"></td>
                <td><div class="rating"></div></td>
                <td class="hidden email">ron.tornambe@bunkerhill.com</td>
                <td class="hidden id">101</td>
                <td><input class="hidden writer-rating" value="3"></td>
```

How can this happen?

Comment: no clue yet, but is the tick-count identical with the row-count?

Comment: Actually, it is, but @ritzer nailed it. I had a backtick after a checkbox. Why don't I see his comment any longer?

Comment: A classic case of a program doing exactly what you tell it to ;)

Comment: I don't see it either... still, it's strange, that they get inserted at a different point. maybe jquery has it's hand in this? (in append)

Comment: @rontornambe I deleted it because the backticks are showing up at a different place which let me believe that this wasn't the reason.

Comment: @Rizier123 - many thanks. your suggestion did indeed remove the backticks!

Comment: which still makes me curious why this did happen. That they did show up at a different place....I have no idea. @Rizier123, you? jQuery?

Comment: @Jeff Well PHP wasn't it, probably. So some JS/JQuery must have moved it. Maybe disable JS when you load the page and see where they show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have in your code this:

```
<td><input type='checkbox' class='sendemail' /></td>`
```

There at the end is backtick, which propagates to output. Delete it.